# Can Bayesian methods be used for fixed horizon hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

I wonder if it is possible to use Bayesian methods to do fixed horizon hypothesis testing. If it is possible, what test statistics should I use? What formula should I use to calculate sample sizes? I can't find such information in any textbooks.

Comment: Can you please explain *fixed horizon hypothesis testing*? What is it? Some reference/link?